# Php unknown syntax

Tags: css, datatables

I Just learn php and creating a crud of a table. And I found syntax of class said :

table class="table table-bordered table-stripped table-hover table-data

Can Anyone can explain the syntax part of table-data what is that mean?
cause when I erase those syntax my table sort and searching feature is missing.

thanks,

joe

Comment: I am assuming you are using DataTables. So you might be initializing the datatable using the ``table-data`` class name.

Comment: It seems these classes dose not related to PHP and database. I think it's related to HTML and Bootstrap. Bootstrap information about table styles is provided here:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/tables/

Comment: `table-data` seems like a custom class, I think it's better to include your CSS part in the question.

Comment: Please share more details. The given code is not related to PHP. What do you mean by "syntax of class"?